# Monotonicity of Einstein Sum (s-norm)

Tags: fuzzy-set

I am trying to prove that Einstein Sum
$$S_{es}(a,b) = \frac{a+b}{1+ab}$$
is an s-norm operator. But, i got struggle on proving its monotonicity, i.e

If $a\leq c$ and $b \leq d$ then $s_{es}(a,b) \leq s_{es}(c,d)$.

So, i want to prove prove that if $0 \leq a, b, c, d \leq 1$ such that $a\leq c$ and $b \leq d$ then

$$\frac{a+b}{1+ab} \leq \frac{c+d}{1+cd}$$

I've tried to work backward, but got no result. Any suggestion?

Comment: This could use a description of what an $s$-norm is.  Wikipedia redirects to a "T-norm".  If that's the same, then did you make a typo: do you mean "if $a\leq c$ and $b\leq d$ _etc._"?

Comment: My bad. That's what i mean.